# Will nailing vinyl over my wall ruin the paint over time?

Tags: walls, paint, sound-proofing, vinyl

I have some noisy neighbors and my landlord has given me permission to nail mass loaded vinyl over the offending window. The vinyl will remain in place for about 6 months. Is there any risk that over time the vinyl could stick to the paint and ruin the wall when I take it off?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Without more info, the answer has to be "yes; there's a risk." And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know how fresh the paint on that wall is and what the sheen of the paint is (matte, satin, semigloss, etc).  Paint that is glossy and less that.. 6 months old will tend to still stick to things that are hung on the wall (I made up that time frame, but feels right to me).  Even matte paint can have this issue, but it's far less likely.

A good option might be to hang up builders paper (basically kraft paper like grocery bags are made of) to provide an intermediate layer between the paper and the vinyl.  The paper can still stick to very fresh paint, but it is less likely to do so.

Comment: This paint is several years old, should I still get paper?

Comment: After several years you should be fine regardless of the paint type.  If you're worried about the vinyl having and printing or oils or whatever on the surface, paper might still be a good idea to avoid stain transfering.